# How to add class to a parent from child element text value? jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list that has child elements inside it. I want to add the value of .post-meta-boxcolor to the parent li

```
<ul class="course-list">
    <li>

     <div class="course-content">
      <p class="post-meta post-meta-level">Level 2</p>
      <p class="post-meta post-meta-boxcolor">orange</p>
     </div>

    </li>

    <li>

     <div class="course-content">
      <p class="post-meta post-meta-level">Level 2</p>
      <p class="post-meta post-meta-boxcolor">red</p>
     </div>

    </li>

    <li>

     <div class="course-content">
      <p class="post-meta post-meta-level">Level 2</p>
      <p class="post-meta post-meta-boxcolor">lightblue</p>
     </div>

    </li>


</ul>
```

How can i add class to the parent li based on class="post-meta-boxcolor" text or value.

The result that I want is this:

```
<ul class="course-list">
    <li class="orange">

     <div class="course-content">
      <p class="post-meta post-meta-level">Level 2</p>
      <p class="post-meta post-meta-boxcolor">orange</p>
     </div>

    </li>

    <li class="red">

     <div class="course-content">
      <p class="post-meta post-meta-level">Level 2</p>
      <p class="post-meta post-meta-boxcolor">red</p>
     </div>

    </li>

    <li class="lightblue">

     <div class="course-content">
      <p class="post-meta post-meta-level">Level 2</p>
      <p class="post-meta post-meta-boxcolor">lightblue</p>
     </div>

    </li>


</ul>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [addClass](https://api.jquery.com/addClass/) method with a callback as argument like

```js
$('.course-list li').addClass(function() {
  return $(this).find('.post-meta-boxcolor').text()
})
```

```css
.orange {
  color: orange;
}
.red {
  color: red;
}
.lightblue {
  color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="course-list">
  <li>

    <div class="course-content">
      <p class="post-meta post-meta-level">Level 2</p>
      <p class="post-meta post-meta-boxcolor">orange</p>
    </div>

  </li>

  <li>

    <div class="course-content">
      <p class="post-meta post-meta-level">Level 2</p>
      <p class="post-meta post-meta-boxcolor">red</p>
    </div>

  </li>

  <li>

    <div class="course-content">
      <p class="post-meta post-meta-level">Level 2</p>
      <p class="post-meta post-meta-boxcolor">lightblue</p>
    </div>

  </li>


</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks  @Arun P Johny

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$('.course-list li').addClass(function(){
     return $(this).find('.post-meta-boxcolor').text().replace(/\s/g, '');
});
```